# select package in Java

Tags: java, python, select

I am trying to re-write a Python library in Java. I was wondering if any java package was available which is analogous to the `select` module available in Python.

http://docs.python.org/library/select.html

I have been referred to the nio package but I was wondering if there was a slighly more similar Java implementation.

Comment: Java doesn't have an equivalent of `select()` or `poll()`. Thus, you are stuck with NIO.

Comment: Perhaps you could say what you are trying to do.  There are loads of options/frameworks for doing this sort of thing.

Comment: Java's threads are very light weight in Java 6. Often having one thread per source is the simplest way to process multiple streams.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not unless you are willing to write a [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) wrapper for *select*(2) yourself, or can find one on the 'net. (I looked briefly, and I didn't find one.) That's likely to be a fun little challenge, too, if you want to support Java's notion of an open file (e.g., to map a Java `InputStream` into a Unix file descriptor).

The preferred way to do this in Java is, as you've noted, with `java.nio`. `nio` does have some restrictions, though. The biggest difference between `nio` and *select*(2), aside from the API differences, is that `nio` will only multiplex over network sockets. You can't use it to multiselect open files, for instance.

Comment: I would be very surprised if multi-selecting on files would be more efficient than using multi-threads to read one file each.

Comment: That depends on the application. It also depends on how much multiselecting you have to do. If you have to handle a significant number of open sockets, you're going to run into problems with threads, for instance. Threads don't scale as well as a concurrent model that uses `nio` and `java.util.concurrent`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work for you, but you could try [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) instead of re-writing it in java.

Comment: This is a fair point. The [Jython select module](http://wiki.python.org/jython/SelectModule) hews closely to the CPython *select* module's interface, though it's based on Java channels, so it only works on network sockets, just like `nio`.